# Update a single column on multiple rows with one SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to update a single column over a thousand rows in the database. Normally when I need to do this, I'll do the following:

```
UPDATE [table] SET DATA="FOO" WHERE ID=23;
UPDATE [table] SET DATA="ASD" WHERE ID=47;
UPDATE [table] SET DATA="FGH" WHERE ID=83;
UPDATE [table] SET DATA="JKL" WHERE ID=88;
UPDATE [table] SET DATA="QWE" WHERE ID=92;
UPDATE [table] SET DATA="BAR" WHERE ID=97;
```

I feel like there should be a way to do this easily, but after searching around online, I cannot find a solution.

What I was hoping for was this:

```
-- THIS DOES NOT WORK
UPDATE [table]
  SET DATA=("FOO", "ASD", "FGH", "JKL", "QWE", "BAR") 
  WHERE ID=(23, 47, 83, 88, 92, 9);
```

An important piece of information to note is that I am always setting one column, the same column across a specific set of rows.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL is not SQL Server.

Comment: `[tablename]` does not work in MySQL

Comment: @StevenRogers, you did not accept an answer yet. It does not have to be mine, but please accept an answer so the question is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do it using **insert into ...on duplicate key update**

```
insert into [table](ID,DATA) 
values(23,'FOO'),(47,'ASD'),(54,'DSF')..,
on duplicate key update DATA=values(DATA)
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to modify this so it does not insert a new row if the new data is flawed and there's a row in the new data that is not in the old data?

Comment: How can i simplify, following 100 lines of commands, the command is UPDATE shipping_matrixrate SET condition_to_value =  1 WHERE condition_to_value = 1000;

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) statement which is in the [SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) standard and available in Transact-SQL since SQL Server 2008:

```
MERGE mytable
USING (VALUES (23, 'FOD'),
              (47, 'ASD'),
              (83, 'FGH'),
              (88, 'JKL'),
              (92, 'QWE'),
              ( 9, 'BAR')) AS pairs(id2, data2)
     ON id = id2 
WHEN MATCHED 
     THEN UPDATE SET data = data2
```

The `USING` clause allows to specify a derived table using a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (See example under point D on that page).

Alternatively, the more commonly implemented [SQL:92 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) syntax to do this would be:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    data = 
       CASE id
            WHEN 23 THEN 'FOD'
            WHEN 47 THEN 'ASD'
            WHEN 83 THEN 'FGH'
            WHEN 88 THEN 'JKL'
            WHEN 92 THEN 'QWE'
            WHEN  9 THEN 'BAR'
       END
WHERE  id IN (23, 47, 83, 88, 92, 9);
```

The obvious downside is that you end up specifying the id values twice. You could do without the `WHERE` clause and add `ELSE data` in the `CASE` construct, but then you would actually update all rows, which is inefficient and may have undesired side-effects (via triggers).

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that you are in MySQL. You can use a combination of "Field" and "Elt" functions to do what you need in a single query (beside the `CASE WHEN THEN WHEN THEN WHEN THEN WHEN THEN WHEN THEN WHEN THEN WHEN THEN END` or `IF(<condition>,<output>,if(<condition2>,<output2>, if()))` methods.

```
UPDATE [table] SET DATA=ELT(FIELD(ID,
   13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19),'FOO', 'ASD', 'FGH', 'JKL', 'QWE', 'BAR');
```

This is similar to the `DECODE()` function in Oracle, which I wish had counterparts in other DBMS's.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server

```
UPDATE t1 
set DATA = derived1.NewValue
From
[table] t1 join
(
Select 'Foo' as NewValue, 23 as MyId 
union all Select 'ASD' as NewValue, 47 as MyId 
union all Select 'FGH' as NewValue, 83 as MyId 
) as derived1
on t1.ID = derived1.MyId
```

Note, you can hydrate/populate "derived1" anyway you'd like.  As long as the result set is the correct rows of "NewValue" and "MyId".

Answer (score 1):

one way i could think of is join..The way you are trying to update wont scale

---insert your updates in  a table like below every time you want to update data.

```
create table #test
(
data varchar(2),
id int
)

insert into #test
select 'abc',1
union  all
select 'cde',2
```

now you update your main table like below

```
update mt
set mt.data=t.data
from maintable  mt
join
#test t
on t.id=mt.id
```